# Convert sql Query into codeigniter query

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I can run this query in PHP my admin and it gives me exact result as i want. Now i want to run this query in model as i'm working in `CodeIgniter` so i want this query to be converted in `CodeIgniter` format.

```
SELECT (es.seats-COUNT(ri.id)) as Remaining_Seats 
FROM event_session es, registered_invitees ri 
where ri.session_fk = es.id  and ri.session_fk = 34;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->select('(es.seats-COUNT(ri.id)) as Remaining_Seats');
$this->db->from('`event_session es, registered_invitees ri');
$this->db->where("ri.session_fk = es.id AND ri.session_fk = '34'");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I want the integer value in return

Comment: Thanks That works for me i just returned
$query->row()->Remaining_Seats;

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
$this->db->select('(es.seats-COUNT(ri.id)) as Remaining_Seats')
         ->join('registered_invitees ri', 'ri.session_fk = es.id')
         ->where('ri.session_fk',  '34')
         ->get('event_session es')->row();
```